# Combine 2 Wordpress While Statements in Loop

Tags: wordpress, post, loops

I want to only show posts on a wordpress page that belong to logged in users AND contain a custom meta key "color." I have the code for each option i.e. I can either show posts belonging to logged in users or posts with a meta key = color but I cant work out how to combine both so both conditions need to be true. Below are the 2 pieces of code i'm working with:

```
<!-- If Logged In -->
<?php       
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
while($author_posts->have_posts() : $author_posts->the_post(); 
get_template_part( 'content', 'page', 'the_meta()' );
?>

<!-- If Posts Contains Color Meta -->
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query('meta_key=color');
while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
endwhile;
?>
```

Does anyone know how to combine them so posts that match both conditions are shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :   
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

       $query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID, 'meta_key' => 'color');
       $result = new WP_Query($query);

       while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post(); 
           get_template_part( 'content', 'page', 'the_meta()' );
       endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```